# GraphQL query entries by DateTime field between two dates

Tags: datetime, query, graphql

I am trying to query entries in GraphQL by custom DateTime field value.
It works with the base String value like ">=2020-10-01",

However querying between two dates like "['and', '>=2020-10-01', '<2020-11-01']" it gives me an empty result.

What will be the correct query variable here?

Thank you

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After trying multiple options found an answer:

[image]